# Can one buy a car on Hol Hamoed?

Tags: halacha, transactions, vehicles-transportation, chol-hamoed

One is restricted to do certain types of melachos (creative work) during hol hamoed.

Do these restrictions extend to prohibiting the purchase of a new car?

Comment: Do you need it on chol hamoed? Could you have bought it before chag?

Comment: @DoubleAA, say you started shopping a month before the chag, and during the chag you happen to see a good deal. Yes it will be used during the chag, although it might not be practical if the process takes about 2-3 days with the DMV and the like.

Answer (score 3):

[Rabbi Mordechai Eliyahu Zatzal](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/751) says that it is permitted to purchase a car on Chol Hamoed if he is afraid that after Yom Tov he will not find such a quality car or the price will change.

> מותר לקנות מכונית וכד' אם יש חשש שאחרי החג לא ימצא כמוה בטיב או במחיר
>   (שו"ע תקלט סע' ה).